# woocommerce check out field

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, paypal, woocommerce

I use checkout by amazon or by paypal express checkout, when user clicks on amazon or on pay pal , when control comes back on my site after logging in paypal or on amazone, I have no extra checkout field, that I created using checkout field editor ('How did you find Us?'), Just the order summary is listed, how can I show my extra created field?
I use woocommerce plugin for shopping cart.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout fields are only shown on checkout, when someone returns from a payment gateway (paypal in your case) by default they are logged in. So in order to show a text area after someone returns from paypal, you will have to edit the order summary template and add a check to it. So if the user is reffered from paypal, only then they will see your custom form.

A better way would be by using "woocommerce_payment_complete" hook and redirect the user to another page where you can add your custom functionality/ Gravity form shortcode or use contact form 7.